# Writing specific number of bytes in file

Tags: java

I have the array listed below:

I want to write these bytes in a file until the file reaches a size of 1029 bytes . Any ideas?

I tried this code but it does not seem to work :

```
public static byte[] aSnouty = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 49, 45, 50, 51, 52, 53};

File file = new File(filename);
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    do {
        fos.write(aSnouty); 
    } while(file.length()!=1029);

} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Writing 15 bytes at a time will never get you a 1029 byte file. 15 into 1029 doesn't go, it's impossible. If you want to stop when it goes *past* 1029 bytes, test `while(file.length()<1029)`, otherwise  you'll need to add some more explanation of what should happen, and what's going wrong.

Comment: Not only what @TessellatingHeckler said, but you're also not [`flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--)ing the output stream, which means you're not in control of when the data is being written to disk.  Which means that the `file.length()` call isn't giving you the length of the file with the new data.

Comment: @Powerlord Should the fos.close(); go just after the loop?

Comment: @alkis1995 Yes, assuming you're no longer doing anything with `fos`.

Comment: It also says that the bytes of the file should appear randomly(always from the table though) and follow normal distribution(dafuq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution starting from the code you provided:

```
    byte[] aSnouty = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 49, 45, 50, 51, 52, 53};

    File file = new File("C:/users/BXM0121/testTenTwentyNine.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    int fileSizeInBytes = (int) file.length();
    final int maxFileSize = 1029;
    try {
        do {

            if ((maxFileSize - fileSizeInBytes) < aSnouty.length)
            {
                fos.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(aSnouty, 0, maxFileSize-fileSizeInBytes));
                break;
            }
            fos.write(aSnouty); 
            fileSizeInBytes += aSnouty.length;
        } while (file.length() != maxFileSize);

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        fos.close();
    }
```

Edit: I see your comment about normal distribution and that's a whole different beast. I didn't code for that.